# solid state relay for 3d printer not switching power

Tags: solid-state-relay

i have a 3d printer controlled by a rasberry pi model 4b. my aim is to use a ssr to turn on and off power to the main board via the rasberry pi. its a dc/dc ssr wired into the power line between the psu and the main board with the control side connected to the rasberry pi.

this is the relay i used

[https://www.amazon.com/Alinan-SSR-40DD-Output-Single-Semi-Conductor/dp/B09P8B97ZN/ref=sr_1_3?crid=V2JJE2TTC4Y2&keywords=ssr40+dd&qid=1707571230&sprefix=ssr40+dd%2Caps%2C329&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09P8B97ZN)

so first i wired in the control and confirmed that it was working. i then went to wire in the power line. i put the feed line from the psu to number 2, that being the positive plus sign and the line going to the board connected to the 1 - terminal. with this configuration when toggelling the switch nothing happenned.

i then swapped around the power terminals and whether the control side is toggled or not the board is permanently powered on.

did i damage the relay with the first incorrect configuration on the power line so much so that when i switched it around to the "correct" way it is just continious power, or is a ssr simply the wrong type of relay to be used?

i know there are other types of relays that i can use but i would still like to get it working with the ssr if at all possible. i guess its just the challenge.

Comment: Please capitalise your writing properly. It affects legibility and credibility.

Comment: What was the used voltage on the control side and how could you confirm that it was working?

Comment: Hi Jens, the voltage was 3.3v. i confirmed it was working by toggling through a gui for my rasberry pi to which the led on the ssr lit up.

Comment: Was there a datasheet that came with the SSR? The datasheet will tell you the correct wiring configuration(most of the time).